# Proof of Cauchy Riemann Equations in Polar Coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis

How would one go about showing the polar version of the Cauchy Riemann Equations are sufficient to get differentiability of a complex valued function which has continuous partial derivatives?

I haven't found any proof of this online.

One of my ideas was writing out $r$ and $\theta$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, then taking the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ and showing the Cauchy Riemann equations in the Cartesian coordinate system are satisfied. A problem with this approach is that derivatives get messy.

What are some other ways to do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*I happen to have some notes on this question. What follows here is the usual approach, it's just multivariate calculus paired with the Cauchy Riemann equations. I have an idea for an easier way, I'll post it as a second answer in a bit if it works.*

If we use polar coordinates to rewrite $f$ as follows:
$$ f(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta)) = u(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))+iv(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta)) $$
we use shorthands $F(r,\theta)=f(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))$ and $U(r,\theta )=u(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))$ and $V(r,\theta )=v(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))$. We derive the CR-equations in polar coordinates via the chain rule from multivariate calculus,
$$ U_r = x_ru_x + y_ru_y = \cos(\theta)u_x + \sin(\theta)u_y \ \
\text{and} \ \ U_{\theta} = x_{\theta}u_x + y_{\theta}u_y = -r\sin(\theta)u_x + r\cos(\theta)u_y $$
Likewise,
$$ V_r = x_rv_x + y_rv_y = \cos(\theta)v_x + \sin(\theta)v_y \ \
\text{and} \ \ V_{\theta} = x_{\theta}v_x + y_{\theta}v_y = -r\sin(\theta)v_x + r\cos(\theta)v_y $$
We can write these in matrix notation as follows:
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{l} U_r \\ U_{\theta} \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{ll} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -r\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta) \end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{l} u_x \\ u_y \end{array} \right] \ \ \text{and} \ \ 
\left[ \begin{array}{l} V_r \\ V_{\theta} \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{ll} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -r\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta) \end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{l} v_x \\ v_y \end{array} \right] $$
Multiply these by the inverse matrix: $\left[ \begin{array}{ll} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -r\sin(\theta) & r\cos(\theta) \end{array} \right]^{-1} = \frac{1}{r}\left[ \begin{array}{ll} r\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ r\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{array} \right]$ to find
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{l} u_x \\ u_y \end{array} \right] = \frac{1}{r}\left[ \begin{array}{ll} r\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ r\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{l} U_r \\ U_{\theta} \end{array} \right] =  \left[ \begin{array}{l} \cos(\theta)U_r - \tfrac{1}{r}\sin(\theta)U_{\theta} \\ 
\sin(\theta)U_r + \tfrac{1}{r}\cos(\theta)U_{\theta} \end{array} \right] $$
A similar calculation holds for $V$. To summarize: 
$$ u_x = \cos(\theta)U_r - \tfrac{1}{r}\sin(\theta)U_{\theta} \ \ \ \ v_x = \cos(\theta)V_r - \tfrac{1}{r}\sin(\theta)V_{\theta} $$
$$ u_y =\sin(\theta)U_r + \tfrac{1}{r}\cos(\theta)U_{\theta} \ \ \ \ v_y =\sin(\theta)V_r + \tfrac{1}{r}\cos(\theta)V_{\theta} $$
The CR-equation $u_x=v_y$ yields:
$$ (A.) \ \ \cos(\theta)U_r - \tfrac{1}{r}\sin(\theta)U_{\theta} =  \sin(\theta)V_r + \tfrac{1}{r}\cos(\theta)V_{\theta} $$
Likewise the CR-equation $u_y=-v_x$ yields:
$$ (B.) \ \ \sin(\theta)U_r + \tfrac{1}{r}\cos(\theta)U_{\theta} = -\cos(\theta)V_r + \tfrac{1}{r}\sin(\theta)V_{\theta}$$
Multiply (A.) by $r\sin(\theta)$ and $(B.)$ by $r\cos(\theta)$ and subtract (A.) from (B.):
$$ \boxed{U_{\theta} = -rV_r} $$
Likewise multiply (A.) by $r\cos(\theta)$ and $(B.)$ by $r\sin(\theta)$ and add (A.) and (B.): 
$$ \boxed{rU_r = V_{\theta}} $$
Finally, recall that $z = re^{i\theta}=r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$ hence
\begin{align} \notag
 f'(z) &= u_x+iv_x \\ \notag
       &= (\cos(\theta)U_r - \tfrac{1}{r}\sin(\theta)U_{\theta})+i(\cos(\theta)V_r - \tfrac{1}{r}\sin(\theta)V_{\theta}) \\ \notag
       &= (\cos(\theta)U_r + \sin(\theta)V_{r})+i(\cos(\theta)V_r - \sin(\theta)U_{r}) \\ \notag &= (\cos(\theta)- i\sin(\theta))U_r + i(\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta))V_r  \\ \notag
       &= e^{-i\theta}( U_r+iV_r)  \notag
\end{align}

Comment: I see, I think the only point of possible problem is knowing that x and y do show up as part of the function,

Comment: @Mike well, we are taking a fact known for $x,y$ and trying to change notation to polar coordinates. There will be $x$ and $y$ somewhere. The key is understanding how to convert both functions and derivatives. You can see if you find my other answer reasonable... there is a jump, see if you can find it.

Comment: Can we express the CR equations just by using equation  A, namely equating the terms adjacent to sine and cosine on both sides?

Comment: @Shemafied I suppose that would also be reasonable. Interesting.

Comment: @james Yes, but the proof you showed is mathematically more sound

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Is there some intuition behind the fact that only *one* CR equation is sufficient to derive *both* polar equations? Or is this just a fortunate result of the symmetry between pairs $u_x$, $v_y$; $u_y$, $v_x$? (sorry for pinging on an answer from 2012)

Comment: @LinearChristmas I'm not sure I understand your question, I think I used both CR equations to derive the polar CR-equations...

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Maybe I am missing something but I was referring to the comparing of coefficients of sines and cosines suggested by Emir. Then we would only need $(A.)$ or $(B.)$ but not both to arrive at the two polar CR equations. And hence having used just one CR equation. (Correct me if I am wrong.)

Comment: No, you are correct, I forgot about Emir's comment (which is in plain sight). I'm not sure what a good answer is to that question, I think it has to do with partial derivatives commuting, I'll try to ponder this further when I have the right mindset. I think it deserves its own Q and A.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook No worries. It is an interesting question indeed; though we won't know exactly *how* interesting until the answer comes about. In any case, should your ponderings prove fruitful $-$ I have a good feeling they will $-$ please do ping me. (I'll do the same if I have an idea... not as likely :)) But a question on its own wouldn't be the worst idea.

Answer (score 11):

We can derive using purely polar coordinates. Start with
\begin{align}
z(r,\theta) &=r\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} \\
f(z) &= u(r,\theta) + \mathrm{i} v(r,\theta)
\end{align}
We define $f'(z)$ using the limit
$$ f'(z) = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{\Delta f}{\Delta z} $$
where
\begin{align}
\Delta f &= \Delta u + \mathrm{i} \Delta v \\
\Delta z &= z(r+\Delta r,\theta + \Delta\theta) - z(r,\theta) \\
&= (r+\Delta r)\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(\theta+\Delta\theta)} - r \,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}
\end{align}
Next, we try to first approach from $\Delta\theta\to 0$,
$$ \Delta z = (r+\Delta r)\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} - r \,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} = \Delta r\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} $$
Therefore when we take the limit,
$$ f'(z) = \lim_{\Delta r\to 0} \frac{\Delta u + \mathrm{i} \Delta v}{\Delta r \,\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}} = \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}}(u_r + \mathrm{i} v_r) \label{a}\tag{1}$$
On the other hand, approaching from $\Delta r\to 0$ first yields
$$\Delta z = r\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(\theta+\Delta\theta)} - r \,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$$
Using the derivative
$$\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(\theta+\Delta\theta)}-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\Delta\theta = \mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}\Delta\theta$$
we get
$$\Delta z = \mathrm{i}r\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}\Delta\theta$$
Therefore
$$f'(z) = \lim_{\Delta\theta\to 0} \frac{\Delta u + \mathrm{i} \Delta v}{\mathrm{i}r\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}\Delta\theta} = \frac{1}{\mathrm{i}r\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}}(u_\theta + \mathrm{i}v_\theta) \label{b}\tag{2}$$
Finally, comparing the real and imaginary parts of ($\ref{a}$) and ($\ref{b}$) gives us what we want:
$$u_r=\frac{1}{r}v_\theta \quad,\quad v_r = -\frac{1}{r}u_\theta$$

---

Reference: Kwong-tin Tang, *[Mathematical Methods for Engineers and Scientists 1](http://www.springer.com/physics/theoretical%2C+mathematical+%26+computational+physics/book/978-3-540-30273-5)* (Springer, 2007)

Comment: I think this is a standard approach though at its present form it is not completely rigorous. But surely this can be made rigorous by applying some MVT argument along one of the lines above.

Answer (score 8):

A less standard approach: Take $\{e_{r},e_{\theta}\}$ as a basis in polar coordinates then the Jacobian matrix for any function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the form:
$$ [df] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} U_r & U_{\theta} \\ V_r & V_{\theta} \end{array} \right] $$
**Define** complex-differentiability via complex linearity of the differential; $df(vw)=df(v)w$ at the point in question for all $v,w \in \mathbb{C}$. In particular this gives the beautiful formula: $df(v)=df(1)v$; this means the first column of the Jacobian fixes the second by complex multiplication. It is geometrically clear that $\frac{1}{r}e_{\theta} = ie_r$. Observe that $e_{\theta} = ire_r$ thus  $df(e_{\theta}) =df(ire_{r})=irdf(e_r)$. On the other hand, $f=U+iV$ and
$$ df(e_r) = U_r+iV_r \qquad \& \qquad df(e_{\theta})=f_{\theta}=U_{\theta}+iV_{\theta} $$
Thus, $U_{\theta}+iV_{\theta}=ir(U_r+iV_r)$ and we derive
$$ \boxed{ U_{\theta} = -rV_r \qquad \& \qquad V_{\theta}=rU_r. } $$

Comment: I would really love to be able to follow through your answer, but I shold first freshen up my Linear arlebra

Answer (score 4):

I understand this topic is somewhat old, but I still feel like I can contribute to it with a derivation in my eyes much simpler.

The key is to understand the *goal*: we want to derive some analogue of the CR-equations, except in polar form. We therefore wish to relate $u_\theta$ with $v_r$ and $v_\theta$ with $u_r$.

Take the CR-equations in the $xy$-plane as an example and expand:
\begin{equation}
u_x = v_y \Leftrightarrow u_\theta \theta_x = v_r r_y.
\end{equation}
Now remember the definitions of polar coordinates and take the appropriate derivatives:
\begin{align*}
x = r\cos\theta \Rightarrow x_\theta = -r\sin\theta \Rightarrow \theta_x = \frac1{-r\sin\theta}\\
y = r\sin\theta \Rightarrow y_r = \sin\theta \Rightarrow r_y = \frac1{\sin\theta}.
\end{align*}
Now fill in the expressions into our expanded CR-equation to find
\begin{align*}
u_\theta \frac1{-r\sin\theta} = v_r \frac1{\sin\theta} \Rightarrow u_\theta = -r v_r.
\end{align*}
In a similar fashion we can also derive
\begin{equation}
u_r = \frac1r v_\theta.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

[image: Here is an easy approach]
Here is an easy approach to derive the Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar form.

Answer (score 1):

With only partial differentiation and algebra. From what we already know of complex functions:

$ƒ(z) = u(r,\theta) + iv(r,\theta)$

$z = re^{i\theta} = r\cos\theta +ir\sin\theta = x + iy$

$x(r,\theta)= r\cos\theta,\quad y(r,\theta) = r\sin\theta $

Apply partial derivative and chain rule:

$\frac{∂f}{∂r} = \frac{df}{dz}\frac{∂z}{∂r} = \frac{df}{dz}e^{i\theta} = \frac{df}{dz}\frac1rz$

$\frac{∂f}{∂\theta} = \frac{df}{dz}\frac{∂z}{∂\theta} = \frac{df}{dz}ire^{i\theta} = \frac{df}{dz}iz$

which are also equal to:

$\frac{∂f}{∂r} = \frac{∂u}{∂r} + i\frac{∂v}{∂r}$

$\frac{∂f}{∂\theta} = \frac{∂u}{∂\theta} + i\frac{∂v}{∂\theta}$

then set the equality of $r\frac{∂f}{∂r} = \frac1i\frac{∂f}{∂\theta}$:

$r(\frac{∂u}{∂r} + i\frac{∂v}{∂r}) = -\frac1i(\frac{∂u}{∂\theta} + i\frac{∂v}{∂\theta}) $

and separate the real and imaginary:

$\frac{∂u}{∂r} = \frac1r\frac{∂v}{∂\theta}, \quad \frac{∂v}{∂r} = -\frac1r\frac{∂u}{∂\theta}$

yey :3